# Visual Studio 2010 - Reference to dll in TFS

Tags: c#, .net, dll, tfs

I have a c# project which references some dll.

I want to check in that dll into TFS, to an "Assemblies" folder,
and set the reference to that path.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's not important to this, but I hope you know that official MS Mainstream support of Visual Studio 2010 ends in July of this year.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't like checking binaries into version control.  I only do so when I have no other choice, and if I do I would tend to create a custom nuget package and check that nuget package project into version control, build the package then push it to either a local nuget repository (either a local nuget server, or a binary repository like artifactory or sonatype nexus both of which have open source free versions) or an online nuget repository like ProGet or MyGet.

Then I would use Nuget in package restore mode to download the reference as needed when building.

If you don't want to use Nuget for some reason (and trust me, you should use it, and get past any arguments for why not to use it), then check the DLL into each project that needs it and reference it relatively from the project.

As a last resort, if none of those options will work for you, I would check the DLL into an "archive" folder somewhere in version control, then just copy that file somewhere on your network to be referenced in your project.  This way the file is in version control, and has an absolute reference, but only a single copy in source control... but this will require that someone "remembers" all this, and keeps it up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Typically Version Control Systems do not care what you add to them.

In the past I've typically created a Lib or Library folder to house all of my third party DLLs. This folder is typically created in your Solution or Project. You could then add those files to Source Control.

More recently, I've created Nuget packages for all of my DLLs. This is so I do not have to check them in directly into a Version Control System. Instead, I let Nuget manage my DLL dependencies. Using the Nuget Config and Packages file, you can tell your Solution/Project what files are needed and where to get them. This way you do not bloat your VCS with DLLs.

Comment: I'll try to clarify my question: I know its not a problem to add the dll to tfs, the reference part is what I want. Assuming you have several developpers working on the same solution, and each one with his own file system mappings of the solution, how do you get them all to reference the same dll? I Initially tought of creating a virtual drive for dlls but I want to avoid it

Comment: You really wouldn't want them all referencing the same DLL. Think of it as just a normal code file, you wouldn't want everybody to access the same code file right? When you Pull the latest and/or Create a Branch, you're going to have a local copy of all the code files, including DLLs. Assuming you absolutely wanted them to reference the same DLL, you could just create a Network Share that they all had access to.

Comment: The references to your Assemblies folder are relative references. If the Assemblies folder is in your project after you add the reference to your dll file you'll notice a change like below in your .csproj file:
  <Reference Include=".., Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..., processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\Assemblies\...dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>

Comment: @Y.S - You mean you want to check the DLL into a different project?  And that the developers might map those other projects into other locations?  If so, the solution is to check the DLL into each project that is using it.  Typically you would map your project from the solution root, and you would reference the DLL relatively (not from an absolute path)